# Android How to implement save pdf file as GMail

Tags: android, file, android-intent, intentfilter

I need to get path while saving pdf. It is implemented on GMail via Standart file explorer. Moreover there are inputs which is file name and save button. How can i do the same. Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: The screenshot is from `ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT`, part of [the Storage Access Framework](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/05/03/storage-access-framework-faq.html). It does not give you a "path", but rather a `Uri` that you can use for writing out content.

Comment: When User choose another folder path and rename file default name and  click save, can i get filePath, fileName?

Comment: No. The point behind the Storage Access Framework is to *not* work with files, so the user has flexibility of where and how to store the content. If you do not wish to offer your users this flexibility, use any one of a number of [file/directory chooser libraries for Android](http://android-arsenal.com/tag/35).

Comment: Thank you for your reply:)))) Really appreciated